# check for dialog box in RSelenium

Tags: r, selenium-webdriver

I am using RSelenium to access a wage page. Occasionally there may be dialog boxes displayed on the page if an error occurs. What is the proper way to check if a dialog box is displayed and retrieve its contents if one exists?

This question is really more general: a lot of the functions like `findElement` throw exceptions when an element isn't found. What's the best way to check for an element? It seems cumbersome to have a separate `tryCatch` for every command.

Comment: Can you share the webpage URL and code you used to access it?

Comment: i don't have a particular page in mind: i'm learning how to use Selenium and am using RSelenium intro vignette

Comment: here is an example of a page with a dialog box: http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you chose is a page with frames so first the correct frame needs to be switched to:

```
appURL <- "http://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_confirm"
library(RSelenium)
RSelenium::startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver()
remDr$open()
remDr$navigate(appURL)
# This page has frames
remDr$switchToFrame(remDr$findElement("id", "iframeResult"))
webElem <- remDr$findElement("css", "button")
# visually confirm element
webElem$highlightElement()
# click the button to bring up alert
webElem$clickElement()

# Check the Alert text
> remDr$getAlertText()
[[1]]
[1] "Press a button!"
# Accept the alert. Equivalent to pressing the OK button.
remDr$acceptAlert()
```

Depending on the scenario you may also find the `sendKeysToAlert` and `dismissAlert` methods of the `remoteDriver` class useful.

UPDATE:

As part of the error handling code `RSelenium` keeps track of exceptions and assigns them a status code. You can always try calling using a try then check the status code:

```
> try(remDr$findElement("id", "I DONT EXIST"), TRUE)
> remDr$status
[1] 7
> remDr$statusCodes[which(remDr$statusCodes$Code == remDr$status),]
  Code       Summary                                                                         Detail
3    7 NoSuchElement An element could not be located on the page using the given search parameters.
```

Comment: what is the best way to check if an element is there or not without having an exception thrown? if you can imagine that you access a web page that may or may not have a dialog box and may or may not have frames and may or may not etc. having 10 tryCatch clauses is not awesome..

Comment: my question, to be clear, is how to *check* if something exists and not how to interact with the element

Comment: Yes I understand your question. I think its a fair point and thanks for raising the issue. Currently I raise an error when selenium server throws an exception https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/blob/master/R/errorHandler.R#L189 . I can give the option to change this error to a warning which can be switched on and off if it would help. If so maybe file an issue at https://github.com/ropensci/RSelenium/issues and I will add such a mechanism.

Comment: well i think it would be helpful if there was a function that simply checked if an element existed without returning that element. obviously i can easily write one on my own that tryCatches the exception but it might be nice if it was part of the package. anyways, just my thought

Comment: @Alex RSelenium for the most part is designed as a wrapper around Selenium. Selenium is explicitly designed to throw an error when element is not found and doesnt have a `isElementPresent` method. Interestingly it used to have such a method https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/webdriver/kJqbbLVo40E .

Comment: I see. OK that makes sense why its not in the package then.

Comment: You can always just wrap the call in a `try` see my edit

Comment: by the way, this is a great package. thank you for writing it and making it public